# I am getting string instead array, in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert multiple rows in a table. But it's giving the following error : it's getting string value. My input type is hidden, what should I do to get them in array form ?

[image]

My table looks (no increment id):

[image]

And Codes from my controller is :

```
   public function index(Request $request)
{


    $post_data = array();
    $post_data['total_amount'] = $request->total_amount;  
    $post_data['currency'] = $request->currency;
    $post_data['tran_id'] = uniqid(); // tran_id must be unique

    # CUSTOMER INFORMATION
    $post_data['cus_name'] = $request->full_name;
    $post_data['cus_email'] = $request->email_address;
    $post_data['cus_add1'] = $request->street_address.','.$request- 
    >city.','.$request->state.',Post Code -'.$request->postcode;
    $post_data['cus_add2'] = "";
    $post_data['cus_city'] = "";
    $post_data['cus_state'] = "";
    $post_data['cus_postcode'] = "";
    $post_data['cus_country'] = $request->country;
    $post_data['cus_phone'] = $request->phone_number;
    $post_data['cus_fax'] = "";
    $post_data['enrollable'] = $request->enrollable;
    $post_data['user_id'] = $request->user_id;
    $post_data['package_id'] = implode(',', $request->package_id);
    $post_data['plan_id'] = implode(',', $request->plan_id);
    $post_data['status'] =$request->status;
    $post_data['member_number'] = $request->member_number;
    $post_data['base_id'] = $request->base_id;
    $post_data['base_title'] =  $request->base_title;


    # SHIPMENT INFORMATION
    $post_data['ship_name'] = "Store Test";
    $post_data['ship_add1'] = "Dhaka";
    $post_data['ship_add2'] = "Dhaka";
    $post_data['ship_city'] = "Dhaka";
    $post_data['ship_state'] = "Dhaka";
    $post_data['ship_postcode'] = "1000";
    $post_data['ship_phone'] = "";
    $post_data['ship_country'] = "Bangladesh";

    $post_data['shipping_method'] = "NO";
    $post_data['product_name'] = "Computer";
    $post_data['product_category'] = "Goods";
    $post_data['product_profile'] = "physical-goods";



    $post_data['package_type_id'] = implode(',', $request- 
   >package_type_id);


    # OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
    $post_data['value_a'] = "ref001";
    $post_data['value_b'] = "ref002";
    $post_data['value_c'] = "ref003";
    $post_data['value_d'] = "ref004";

    #Before  going to initiate the payment order status need to insert 
    or update as Pending.

    $update_transections = DB::table('package_plan_fees')
        ->insertGetId([
            'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'enroll_able' => $post_data['enrollable'],
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
            'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
            'status' =>  $post_data['status']
        ]);


    $update_product = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('transaction_id', $post_data['tran_id'])
        ->UpdateorInsert([
            'name' => $post_data['cus_name'],
            'email' => $post_data['cus_email'],
            'phone' => $post_data['cus_phone'],
            'amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'status' => 'Pending',
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'address' => $post_data['cus_add1'],
            'transaction_id' => $post_data['tran_id'],
            'currency' => $post_data['currency'],

            'member_number' =>  $post_data['member_number'],

        ]);



    $payments  = DB::table('payments')
        ->Insert([
                'package_plan_fee_id' => $update_transections,
                'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
                'transaction_no' => $post_data['tran_id'],
                'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
                'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
                'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
                'status' =>  $post_data['status'],
                'currency_id' => $post_data['currency'],
                'payment_date' =>  Carbon::now(),
                'created_at' =>  Carbon::now()
        ]);


    $set_base  = DB::table('package_user')
        ->Insert([
            'base_id' => $post_data['base_id'],
            'base_title' => $post_data['base_title'],
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
            'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
            'currency' => $post_data['currency'],
            'payable_plan_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'created_at' =>  Carbon::now()

        ]);

    $data=[];

    foreach($post_data['package_type_id'] as $key => $no){

        $input=[];

        $input['base_id'] = $post_data['base_id'][$key];
        $input['base_title'] = $post_data['base_title'][$key];
        $input['user_id'] = $post_data['user_id'];
        $input['package_id'] = $post_data['package_id'][$key];
        $input['plan_id'] =  $post_data['plan_id'][$key];
        $input['currency'] = $post_data['currency'][$key];
        $input['payable_plan_amount'] = $post_data['total_amount'] 
        [$key];
        $input['created_at'] =  Carbon::now();

        $data[]=$input;
    }

    $set_base  = DB::table('package_user')->Insert($data);


    $sslc = new SslCommerzNotification();
    # initiate(Transaction Data , false: Redirect to SSLCOMMERZ gateway/ 
   true: Show all the Payement gateway here )
    $payment_options = $sslc->makePayment($post_data, 'hosted');

    if (!is_array($payment_options)) {
        print_r($payment_options);
        $payment_options = array();
    }

}
```

For dd($request->all()) :

[image]

Please feel free to ask if need more info to clarify

Comment: Can you check the stack trace and let us know the exact query that causes that exception?

Comment: @apokryfos The last query causing problem